# Tokenizer can add padding without error, but data collator cannot

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to fine tune a GPT2-based model on my data using the `run_clm.py` example [script](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_clm.py) from HuggingFace.

I have a `.json` data file that looks like this:

```json
...
{"text": "some text"}
{"text": "more text"}
...
```

I had to change the default behavior of the script that used to concatenate input text, because all my examples are separate demonstrations that should not be concatenated:

```py
def add_labels(example):
    example['labels'] = example['input_ids'].copy()
    return example

with training_args.main_process_first(desc="grouping texts together"):
    lm_datasets = tokenized_datasets.map(
        add_labels,
        batched=False,
        # batch_size=1,
        num_proc=data_args.preprocessing_num_workers,
        load_from_cache_file=not data_args.overwrite_cache,
        desc=f"Grouping texts in chunks of {block_size}",
    )
```

This essentially only adds the appropriate `'labels'` field required by CLM.

However since GPT2 has a 1024-sized context-window, the examples should be padded to that length.

I can achieve this by modifying the tokenization procedure like this:

```py
def tokenize_function(examples):
    with CaptureLogger(tok_logger) as cl:
        output = tokenizer(
            examples[text_column_name], padding='max_length') # added: padding='max_length'
        # ...
```

The training runs correctly.

However, I believe this should *not* be done by the tokenizer, but by the data collator instead. When I remove `padding='max_length'` from the tokenizer, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length. Perhaps your features (`labels` in this case) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is expected).
```

And also, above that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jan/repos/text2task/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 716, in convert_to_tensors
    tensor = as_tensor(value)
ValueError: expected sequence of length 9 at dim 1 (got 33)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

To fix this, I have created a data collator that should do the padding:

```
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer, padding='max_length')
```

This is what is passed to the trainer. However, the above error remains.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the error but I'm really unsure about my solution, details below. Will accept a better answer.

This seems to solve it:

```py
data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer, model=model, padding=True)
```

[Found in the documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/data_collator#transformers.DataCollatorForSeq2Seq)

It seems like `DataCollatorWithPadding` doesn't pad the labels?

My problem is about generating an output sequence from an input sequence, so I'm *guessing* that using `DataCollatorForSeq2Seq` is what I actually want to do. However, my data does not have separate `input` and `target` columns, but a single `text` column (that contains a string `input => target`). I'm not really that this collator is intended to be used for GPT2...